# How to make sure groupbox always fit in the screen?

Tags: windows, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to create app. In the form, there is only 3 button in a groupbox. I want to make the groupbox always fit in the screen. The problem is when i minimize the form, there is vertical and horizontal scroll. So i cannot see the whole groupbox border: 
[image]

I want to make the groupbox to minimize without the scroll and i am able to see all the border just like when in the maximize screen as below:
[image]

I have already tried groupbox autosize to true while anchor to top, bottom, right, and left but it is still not working. Any idea how i can achieve this?

Comment: Have you set the Dock property to `DockStyle.Fill`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ib11 said you need to go to `Dock` and select **Fill**. In addition, if you want to make your group box not fill the form but grow with it, you'll probably need to change the `Anchor` to all sides. That's why your previous settings didn't work because anchor doesn't fill the screen, it's just a property to grow with the screen. `Fill` makes it possible so that you can have a group box or any other control always fill the screen.

See this image for dock:

[image: Dock]

See this image for anchor:

[image: Anchor Property set to all sides]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Dock` property of the `GroupBox` to `Fill`.

Like so:

[image: Dock property set to Fill]